# Pointwise, and uniform convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f_n(x) = f(x)^n$. Explain why this sequence does not converge uniformly when $f(x)=1$?

When $f(x)=1$, $f_n(x)$ is $1$ for all $n$. But I don't see why this means there is no uniform convergence. Can't we say $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|1-1|<\epsilon$ which is uniformly convergent?

Comment: The *constant* sequence $(f_n)_n=(1,1,1, \dots)$ indeed converges uniformly to the constant function $1$.

Comment: But what is the difference between the constant sequence and f(x)?

Comment: It is zero, which is lesser than any positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: yes, that is my understanding too, but the problem is asking to show that f(x) does not converge...

Comment: ... then the problem is asking to prove something incorrect. Unless of course, by "$f(x)=1$", the problem meant $f(x)=x$, i.e., "$f$" is the identity function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Does it converge uniformly if f(x)<1? Perhaps there is a typo

Comment: Yes, if $f(x)<1$ then $\{f_n\}\to 0$ uniformly